# How to average difference between many value pairs by index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

and thanks for your help! Without helper columns/rows I'm trying to find the average difference in LVEDi between first and last visits of the patients.

E.g., by hand you would work it out as:

```
(diff for patient a + diff for pt b + diff for pt c)/3 = 
((55-45) + (40-31) + (25-31))/3 = 
(10 + 9 + (-6))/3 =
13/3 =
4.333
```

I'm sure the answer involves indexing with an array function, but I can't get started on how to tackle it!

Any help?

Thanks!

```
      A          | B      | C          | D      | E
 01   Patient ID | Date   | First-Last | LVEDi  | LOTS of similar cols
 02   a          | 3/3/03 | LAST       | 55
 03   a          | 1/1/01 | FIRST      | 45
 04   a          | 2/2/02 |            | 65
 05   b          |        |            | 
 06   b          | 3/2/16 | LAST       | 40
 07   b          |        |            | 
 08   b          |        |            | 
 09   b          | 2/1/12 | FIRST      | 31
 10   c          | 1/7/14 | LAST       | 25
 11   c          |        |            | 
 12   c          | 2/2/03 | FIRST      | 31
 13   c          | 2/2/08 |            | 46
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*` as and `AND` criterion in arrays, so with `MATCH` you search for the instance, where both conditions multiplied are `TRUE` (i.e. `1`). The rest is just filling in your calculation:

```
{=((INDEX(D2:D13,MATCH(1,(A2:A13="a")*(C2:C13="LAST"),0))-INDEX(D2:D13,MATCH(1,(A2:A13="a")*(C2:C13="FIRST"),0)))+(INDEX(D2:D13,MATCH(1,(A2:A13="b")*(C2:C13="LAST"),0))-INDEX(D2:D13,MATCH(1,(A2:A13="b")*(C2:C13="FIRST"),0)))+(INDEX(D2:D13,MATCH(1,(A2:A13="c")*(C2:C13="LAST"),0))-INDEX(D2:D13,MATCH(1,(A2:A13="c")*(C2:C13="FIRST"),0))))/3}
```

And remember to use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` to enter the array.

Comment: It is inelegant, but it satisfies the op's question as is.  I do not see any other means without helper columns or vba.

Answer (score 1):

Found a slightly less verbose method:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,"LAST",A:A,{"a","b","c"})-SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,"FIRST",A:A,{"a","b","c"}))/3
```

[image]

---

EDIT 1

Building on Lukas' comment:

```
=(SUMIF(C:C,"LAST",D:D)-SUMIF(C:C,"FIRST",D:D))/COUNTIF(C:C,"LAST")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this without explicitly stating the patient IDs. The reason is that there are many many of them.

Comment: Not without a helper column, @user3520815 . VBA would be better suited.

Comment: The helper column would be a unique list of the patient IDs, If you already have this then you would simply replace the `{"a","b","c"}` with that reference and change the `3` to `COUNTA(yourreference). You will need to force the array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.   @user3520815

Comment: Actually, with column C we already have a helper column, so we can simply the formula to `=(SUMIF(D:D,"LAST",E:E)-SUMIF(D:D,"FIRST",E:E))/3`. Then you also have no problem with the patient IDs @user3520815

Comment: @LukasV and by adding count we made it work.  See edit.